# How to set WooCommerce shipping parameters directly in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I can't find where the width, length and height values are being set for WooCommerce products in WordPress.

We have a large number of products that are lacking these values and rather than manually update each Product, I plan on writing an update query that can use a wildcard/Like selector.

For instance we have a number of "Dangling Earings" that will all use one set of dimensions and another group that is "Teardrop Earings" that uses a different set of Shipping Dimensions. Their Product Titles are similar to "Red Dangling Earing" and "Gold Teardrop Earing" or "Silver Teardrop Earing"

I've searched out and found that WooCommerce uses and array of values per their  Product Data Schema :
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-Data-Schema

The goal is to apply an UPDATE Query to MySQL based on searching and selecting Products that match LIKE '%Teardrop Earing%' but I just can't find where they are set in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WooCommerce Shipping Parameters are in the `wp_postmeta` table.

After determining your Product Id you can update associated records by using the `post_id` column which is a foreign key.

In this query

```
UPDATE
    `wp_postmeta`
SET
    `meta_value` = '.5'
WHERE
    `meta_key` = '_width' AND `post_id` IN(1856,1858,1859,1862,1863,1864,1866,1868,1869,1870,1874,1875,1877,1881,1885,1889,1926,1927,1930,1931,1932,1935,1937,1942,1943,2050,2052,2056,2057,2059,2060,2064,2106,2116,2117,2118,2120,2122,2125,2199,2202,2205)
```

we assign a value of .5 to the _width parameter for all products that were selected and linked via the "AND `post_id' IN ( x, x, x, etc

Repeat for Length, Height and Weight to complete the Shipping Parameters for your selected products.